# Getting Excel Data Range from Sharepoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am trying to retrieve the data from Excel Sheet on Sharepoint by C# Code.

I can get the value for 1 cell in the excel. But I want the range of values(the whole column). How can i get that ?

```
Suppose on browser, I type :
http://test.net/excel/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/docs/MyExcelFile.xlsm/Model/Ranges('Sheet2!D4')?$format=HTML
```

I get the cell value. But Now I want to get the every value for Column D, how can I get it ?